# Combinatorics and probability (Poker)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many 5-card poker hands are there containing at least 3 of the 4 suits? There are 52 cards in a deck and 13 cards of each suit.

Please check over my work and point me in the right direction for the last 2 parts.

The first card can be any suit (out of 4) and any card (out of 13). So 4 × 13.
The second card be be any suit (now out of 3) and any card (out of 13). So 3 × 13.
The third card be be any suit (now out of 2) and any card (out of 13). So 2 × 13.
I don't know how to find the possibilities for the fourth and fifth card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As pointed out, this is indeed incorrect. Please refer to the link in the comments for the proper method.

Split it up into cases: When there are three suits and when there are four suits.

Three suits:

Fourth card has to be among the three suits already chosen, as does the fifth. Among three suits, we have 39 cards (3 * 13). Since we have already picked out three, there remains 36. So there are 36 ways to pick fourth card, and 35 to pick the fifth.

Four suits:

Fourth card has to be among a new suit. There are 13 possibilities. Fifth is any card not already picked. 52 - 4 = 48. So there are 48 possibilities.

Therefore, the number of hands are the number of hands with three suits and those with fours suits added together:

$$Total = (4*13)(3*13)(2*13)(36)(35)+(4*13)(3*13)(2*13)(13)(48)$$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  See the solutions to the same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543272/how-many-5-cards-poker-hands-are-there-containing-at-least-3-of-the-4-suits/1543535#1543535).