# How many different 5 cards hands are there containing all the four suits?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Given a deck of $52$ cards, I'm trying to calculate how many hands there are containing all four suits. The result I'm supposed to get is $685464$, but I'm not sure about the method to be used.

**My attempt**

1. I have found [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543272/how-many-5-cards-poker-hands-are-there-containing-at-least-3-of-the-4-suits), so I understand that the answer will be the number of suits to be chosen (i.e., ${n \choose 1}$, with $n=4,3,2,1$) times the number of cards to be chosen (${13 \choose 2}$ for the repeated suit and ${13 \choose 1}$  for the non-repeated ones), so

$$
N={4 \choose 1}{13 \choose 2}·{3 \choose 1}{13 \choose 1}·{2 \choose 1}{13 \choose 1}·{1 \choose 1}{13 \choose 1} = 4112784
$$
But it is 6 times bigger than the expected result.

2. I have also thought about computing the number as the product of the number of options to pick a card from a suit, ${13 \choose 1}$, four times, and the number of options of picking a card out of the remaining $48$: ${48 \choose 1}$, so

$$N={13 \choose 1}^4{48 \choose 1} = 1370928$$

But it is now 2 times bigger than the expected result.

Why do these approaches fail? What would be the correct way?

Comment: In the first, putting the factors of $3$ and $2$ in means you are insisting on ordering the unduplicated suits.  So you must divide by $3\times 2$ to remove that.  The second double counts every case (as, if you have cards $A,B$ in the duplicated suit, you count it once taking $A$ to be the extra card, and again taking $B$ to be the extra card).

Comment: (2) is what  thought of. Note that you're counting every hand twice, so you divide by 2 at the end. (THe hand AS AC AD AH KH got counted twice, once when the first heart you chose was AH and KH was the extra card at the end, once vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was slightly too long for a comment, so it became an answer.

(1) Consider the suits to be in a fixed order, for instance $\clubsuit$, $\diamondsuit$, $\heartsuit$, $\spadesuit$. Fix a $5$-cards poker hand with all four suits, and rearrange it so that we have first the suit with two cards, then the remaining three suits in the above fixed order. The hand is of the shape $AABCD$, when only suits are shown. This uniquely determines the hand, and counting we get $4=\binom 41$ possibilities for the choice of $A$ among $\clubsuit$, $\diamondsuit$, $\heartsuit$, $\spadesuit$, then $\binom{13}2$ possibilities for the cards $AA$, then each $13=\binom{13}1$ for the $B$, the $C$, and the $D$ card. The obtained total number is thus:
$$
\binom 41\cdot \binom{13}2\cdot \binom{13}1^3=685464\ .
$$
The value in $(1)$ in the OP also has the factors $\binom 31$ and $\binom 21$, using them would count each $AABCD$ with the above convention also realized in the six cases of a permutation of $BCD$:

```
AABCD
AABDC
AACBD
AACDB
AADBC
AADCB
```

(2) Let us refine this second way of counting, so that we definitively do not count a hand twice. Fix a hand. Reorder it as follows. The first four cards are in the fixed order of the suits. For one of them we have a choice. Alice will take the bigger card among the two. Then at the last place Alice puts the lower card from this doubly represented suit. So Alice gets a hand of the shape $\clubsuit\diamondsuit\heartsuit\spadesuit X$. But $X$ is not freely chosen among the remained $48$ cards, it has to be lower than the card $A$ already chosen in the same suit.
Bob uses the similar scheme, but takes first the lower card among the two, and puts at the end the bigger card in the same suit.

If we use the counting from (2) for the shape $\clubsuit\diamondsuit\heartsuit\spadesuit X$
$$
\binom{13}1^4\cdot\binom{48}1\ ,
$$
with $X$ arbitrary among the remained $48$ cards, remained after the choice of the first four $\clubsuit\diamondsuit\heartsuit\spadesuit$,
then we get a hand, which - as it is -  ordered either in the sense of Alice, or in the sense of Bob. Each hand is thus counted twice. We have to divide by two to get the right answer.

Later EDIT: I will give an example for (2), since often words do not determine exactly what they were supposed to describe. The order of operations may count, the ordering may count, etc. - and combining the pieces of the puzzle is simpler checked with an example. Let us consider the following "unordered" hand:
$$
Q\heartsuit\ ,\
9\diamondsuit\ ,\ 
K\heartsuit\ ,\
10\spadesuit\ ,\ 
8\clubsuit\ .
$$
In the OP it is counted somewhere among the $N=13^4\cdot 48$ cases, let us see where... For this let us pre-sort the hand, and impose after pre-sorting for the first four cards, (the ones counted via the $13^4$ factor,) the order fixed above. But (even) with this restriction, we do not have a determined sorted hand, since we (can) count the above sample hand *twice*, explicitly in the following two orders:
$$
\begin{aligned}
H_1 &= 
8\clubsuit\ ,\ 
9\diamondsuit\ ,\ 
\color{red}{Q\heartsuit}\ ,\
10\spadesuit\ ,\ &&\text{ and remaining card }K\heartsuit\ ,
\\
H_2 &= 
8\clubsuit\ ,\ 
9\diamondsuit\ ,\ 
K\heartsuit\ ,\
10\spadesuit\ ,\ &&\text{ and remaining card }\color{red}{Q\heartsuit}\ ,
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This is the reason for introducing Alice and Bob above. They have each a sorting strategy that determines the hand. Alice would sort the above sample hand obtaining $H_2$. Bob will sort it obtaining $H_1$. It is "hard" to count the hands seen by Alice separatedly, or the ones of Bob. But we take them together, and count the total easily, it is $13^4$ for the possibilities of the first $4$ cards in the four different suits, ordered by the suit order, times $48$ for the possibilities for a final fifth card. We know that we get the doubled number of possible hands.

Comment: Okay, now case $(1)$ is clear to me, but I am still unclear about case $(2)$: combinations have been used, which do not account for the order (in contrast to permutations). Then, where does the duplicity due to the order in the formula come from?

Comment: An example was added to (2), i hope things are more clear now! Please do not hesitate to ask, if there are still unclear issues, this helps me a lot to understand from a didactic point of view where are the difficulities related to such combinatorial problems. (And be sure, many other readers may have the same questions... The same questions i would have asked some many years ago...)

Comment: Thank you very much! But I'm sorry, I still don't see it clearly yet... As I understand it, the formula for the [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) does not account for the order in which the elements are chosen. Why does, then, the formula $(2)$ reflect the duplicity of your example? Is it due to the fact that different combinations are being multiplied...?

Comment: I'll try to make the difference clear here. "Combinatorial counting" is more or less the following process, we have a "complicated" set $\mathcal H$ and want its cardinality. This is a "hard" problem say. We construct a more or less complicated **bijection** $f:\mathcal H\to\mathcal E$, where the target $\mathcal E$ is easy or easier. Best, it is a cartesian product. Here, let $\mathcal H$ be the set of $5$-cards hands. You count and want to use $$\mathcal F=\{\ (a,b,c,d;x)\ :\ (a,b,c,d)\in\clubsuit\times\diamondsuit\times\heartsuit\times\spadesuit\ ,\ x\not\in\{a,b,c,d\}\ \}\ .$$What is $f$?

Comment: With the notations as in the above comment and in the answer, i consider the bijection:$$g:\mathcal F\to \mathcal H\times\{\text{ Alice , Bob }\}$$defined as follows. Let $(a,b,c,d;x)$ be an element in $\mathcal F$, which has $13^4\times 48$ elements. Then we map it to $(\ \{a,b,c,d,x\}\ ,\text{ Alice })$ if $(a,b,c,d,x)$ is sorted as Alice usually sorts the cards, else to $(\ \{a,b,c,d,x\}\ ,\text{ Bob })$, since Bob sorts them in this way. This *is* well defined, and a bijection.

Comment: Ok, I think now I got it, thank you